# How to get the number of occurrences of maximum value in a given array

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a logic where I need to find the number of times the maximum value occurs in a given range.

**Example:**

For example, if input array is `[5, 4, 5, 3, 2]` 
Now I will provide an array of queries which represent the index positions [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

These index positions indicate the starting position of my input array.

Expected output is [2,1,1,1,1]

**Explanation:**

index 0 to n means input array is [5, 4, 5, 3, 2]. Here max element is 5 and it occurs 2 times

index 1 to n means input array is [4, 5, 3, 2]. Here max element is 5 and it occurs 1 times

index 2 to n means input array is [5, 3, 2]. Here max element is 5 and it occurs 1 times

index 3 to n means input array is [3, 2]. Here max element is 3 and it occurs 1 times

index 4 to n means input array is [2]. Here max element is 2 and it occurs 1 times

Now This is the code I came up with:

```
public static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> input, List<Integer> indexList) {
    // Write your code here
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < indexList.size(); i++) {
        int index = indexList.get(i);
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = index; j < input.size(); j++) {
            int data = input.get(j);
            if (data > max) {
                max = data;
                count = 1;
            } else if (data == max) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        list.add(count);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this in less time complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple O(n) algo should do the job. Just update `max` value and its `count` while traversing from the end of the array.

Java code:

```
public static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> indexList) {
    int n = data.size();
    int[]result = new int[n];
    int max = data.get(n - 1);
    int count = 1;
    result[n - 1] = 1;
    for(int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--){
         if(max == data.get(i)){
            count++;
         }else if(max < data.get(i)){
            max = data.get(i);
            count = 1;
         }
         result[i] = count;
    }
    // Populate result
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i : indexList){
        list.add(result[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the approach used in this code?

Comment: @learner anything you don't understand ?  I could focus on that.

Comment: I just saw your update on max and count variables, it is clear now